# iOS Background Fetch called even at first launch of the App

Tags: ios, appdelegate, background-fetch

I have successfully implemented `Background Fetch` for my iOS app. But, when I run the project, it also gets called even when App launches for the first time and that's what I need to neglect.

I have not put any API call to server in `Application delegate` methods, I have just made a call to server in following way:

```
# pragma mark
# pragma mark -  Background Fetch Utility

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{    
    NSLog(@"---------- Background Fetch ----------");

    [self getUpdatesFromServer:^(int fetchResult) {

        switch (fetchResult)
        {
            case FETCH_RESULT_NEW_DATA:
            {
                [self fireUpdatesNotification:[Notifications getUnreadCount]];
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                break;
            }

            case FETCH_RESULT_NO_DATA:
            {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
                break;
            }

            case FETCH_RESULT_FAILED:
            {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

May be this is happening as I am debugging the App, but I am not sure.
Any idea on that ?

Comment: Can you use some sort of flag inside your app to determine if it's appropriate to fetch the data. Like `User.shared?.isAuthenticated` or `UserDefaults.standard.isTutorialComplete` or whatever should ignore the first fetch?

Comment: You are right @JohnDough.. But, can I neglect it by not doing any code if there is something I need to configure?